# Twitter bootstrap media-grid: How to add a caption to the thumbnails

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap and the 'media-grid' feature to display some thumnabils of images. Here is what it looks like right now: http://jsfiddle.net/vXMMA/

What I would like to do is add a caption to these thumbnails.. can someone offer some idea on what changes to CSS I would need to make to enable this.

Comment: like this : http://jsfiddle.net/vXMMA/1/

Comment: Thats pretty good.. Thanks.. can you help me figure out how to 'center' it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### HTML

```
  <li>
    <a href="#">
        <legend >Caption</legend>
        <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/140x90" alt="">
    </a>
  </li>
```

#### CSS

```
legend { margin:3px; text-align:center;width:100%}
```

**[`Working DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/vXMMA/24/)**

Comment: The demo works, but I can't get it to work in this very minimal test case: http://pastebin.com/s8gdiGhg

Comment: the `style` property should be `margin:3px; text-align:center;width:100%`, not `legend { margin:3px; text-align:center;width:100%}`. This is because you don't use a definer in an inline style. See the demo in my post below.

Answer (score 13):

The latest bootstrap comes with a `.caption` class that you can add to your thumbnail grid, you can place it above or below your media grid quite easily and it works like so:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
    <li class="span2">
      <div class="caption">
        <h5>Caption above</h5>
      </div>
      <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
        <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/160x120">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="span2">
      <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
        <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/160x120">
      </a>
      <div class="caption">
        <h5>Caption below</h5>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="span2">
      <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
        <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/160x120">
      </a>
      <div class="caption">
        <h5>Caption below</h5>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="span2">
      <div class="caption">
        <h5>Caption above</h5>
      </div>
      <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
        <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/160x120">
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<hr>

<ul class="thumbnails">
    <li class="span4">
    <div class="caption">
      <h5>Caption above</h5>
    </div>
      <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
        <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/160x120">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="span4">
      <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
        <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/160x120">
      </a>
    <div class="caption">
      <h5>Caption below</h5>
    </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can center the caption inside the image container by just modifying the `.caption` class and adding the `text-align: center` property, like so:

```
.caption {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2BBnR/

**Note** Noticed this post is old, so the other method posted is irrelevant with the latest bootstrap, the `.media-grid` class is no longer used.

Comment: Realised it was the wrong version of bootstrap, then I came here and found the perfect answer [which also pointed this out]. Thanks a heap! - EDIT: _Can't award the bounty for another 15 hours... keep a lookout!_

Comment: @AT Yeah, thats the thing with the bootstrap, you always have to keep a lookout in the changelog to see what was changed or moved/removed. I'm glad i was of help.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `<legend>` tag before or after each image, and add the `text-align:center` style to the image grid.

See [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vXMMA/139/), it works great.